# Why does my nested query slow the SQL server so much?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my query.  It took 8 seconds to draw 12 results from less than 30 possible. What's going on here? The server is REALLY fast with some very complex queries, but not this...

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where post_id IN
  (SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN 
     (select id from wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'ads') 
      AND meta_key like 'image1')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the select is executed for each row in WHERE. Place it in the FROM section instead. Like this.

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta t1
     JOIN wp_postmeta t2 ON t2.meta_value=t1.post_id AND meta_key like 'image1'
     JOIN wp_posts t3 ON t3.id=t1.post_id AND post_type = 'ads'
```

Comment: This was interesting - it didn't actually speed things up too much- possibly, I'm misunderstanding the ambiguous meta_value and meta_key fields - I assumed the first ambiguous meta_value was t1.meta_key, and the meta_key was t2.meta_key - returned 0 rows after 2 seconds.

Comment: May be the condition **ON t2.meta_value=t1.post_id** is not correct. Use t2.corresponding_post_id_field rather than t2.meta_value

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need wildcards I would change LIKE to = (equals), depending on the database and query optimizer, that might have an impact. Also, why did you nest the SELECT meta_value twice? Shouldn't the query be (without the outer clause):

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='image1' AND post_id IN (
SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'ads')
```

or

```
SELECT a.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta a WHERE a.meta_key='image1' AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM wp_posts b WHERE b.post_type = 'ads' AND b.id=a.post_id)
```

or

```
SELECT a.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta a JOIN wp_posts b ON b.id=a.post_id WHERE 
a.meta_key='image1' AND b.post_type = 'ads'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Good to hear. The like operator allows wildcards, e.g. "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%image%'" - would return all rows where the field "meta_key" contains the string "image" (anywhere in the content). Anyway, such queries are often costly because the lack of support to index for such queries (for traditional databases) so the engine need to perform a scan where each row is examined one-by-one (called a table scan). The MS SQL Server Query Optimizer can detect constant LIKE-strings and actually performs a fast index-seek if the wildcard % is not in the beginning of the string.